# how can i use pgcrypto to login in postgres 9

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pgcrypto

This code is not working:

```
select * 
         from persons 
         where lower(email) = lower({email}) 
         and (password = crypt('{password}', password))
         and approved = 1
         and now() between start_date and coalesce(end_date, current_timestamp );
```

the code i have to set the hash works fine:

```
Insert into persons (
          person_id
 ,        name_first
 ,        name_last
 ,        email
 ,        phone
 ,        username
 ,        password
 ,        start_date
 ,        approved
 ,        superuser)
      values
      (
        nextval('PERSON_ID_SEQ')
 ,        {name_first}
 ,        {name_last}
 ,        {email}
 ,        {phone}
 ,        'username'
 ,        crypt('{password}', gen_salt('md5'))
 ,        now()
 ,        0
 ,        0
        )
```

but i cannot seem to get the bit right that checks the hash against the entered password. 
I want to do the check in the where clause so i can return the persons row when it matches.

Thanks in advance
Martin

Comment: Why is {password} in quotes but {email} is not?  Yank the crypt call out of the where clause and put it in the select list, so you can see what is actually happening.

Comment: Did you check whether your select works without other constraints (like startdate, approved, ...)?

Comment: What is the data type of the `password` column?  Note that `pwhash` would be a better column name!

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the problem into smaller bites... see what
    select crypt('{password}', 'hello') 
gets you, and whether anything in the table matches.

Also, the date comparison does not look like a very good idea, as it assumes instantaneous / atomic evaluation of two different time-variable expressions.

Explicitly lowercasing the email is a bit silly unless for some reason the column is using a case-sensitive collation...